# Multires Normal Baking Leaving Blank Image

Tags: texture-baking

I know there is a question with this same wording, but the solution given is not working for me.

I have a "Venom" head that is modeled and ready to bake out a normal map.

I have tried setting the multires "Preview" to 0 through 5, while keeping "Render" and "Sculpt" at 5.  Note, while the multires is set to "not visible" below, I tried with and without visibility enabled.

[image: Multires Settings]

Regardless, the Normal Map only bakes a blank normal map.

[image: Blank Normal Map]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this after messing around for about 45 minutes - posted anyway in case someone else is as boneheaded.  The multires needs to be set to "Render".  Once I did this, it worked fine.

EDIT: To clarify, the multires modifier "render button" (the button that determines whether or not the modifier is used during renders) must be "on" when baking the normals.